# :before element overlapping child elements

Tags: html, css, position, z-index, pseudo-element

I'm having trouble getting my head around an absolutely positioned :before element. I'm after a big quote mark to sit behind a testimonial. I used a :before element as it is a font and is therefore scalable for retina displays, saves an extra http request for the image (I don't have any other images I could make a sprite with) and it also affords me more flexibility of position (a background image would need padding on the left of the element, which would mean playing about with my grid and losing uniformity across other pages I'm using the CSS on).

Hope that makes sense! The problem I'm encountering is that the :before element is covering the text above it. Not much of an issue if it's just text (although still an issue), but there's a link there that isn't completely clickable…

Here's a jsFiddle of my issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/tempertemper/KzQZQ/

I'd assume as the :before is on the li element it would sit behind the blockquote and cites but it doesn't look like that's the case.

I've tried z-index and can't seem to get it all working properly. I've also tried changing the blockquote and cite's position value but no joy.

Thanks for taking a look :)

Comment: What browser are you working in? Just mobile? Firefox has some purported issues with position properties on :before pseudo-elements (http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-before) but I can't seem to reproduce the error in my Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: I've tested it in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari, all on Mac, and it's doing the same on all 4. Try hovering over the first cite of my jsFiddle and your pointer won't change until you're to the right of the text. I guess it's because the “ is above/covering the element. Weird!

Comment: Ahhh! That makes a lot more sense. Why not simply set a " image to be the background of the blockquote? That is pretty common practice.

Comment: Hi @thez, I'm trying to move away from that as I'm going retina! But I don't want the extra http request and filesize (although filesize wouldn't really be an issue for a single colour .png like that I guess) plus I want the “ to sit outside of its container and I don't want to fake it with padding and negative margins. PeterVR seems to have cracked it but it's not working on the actual page I'm developing which is odd (http://tempertemper.net/index2)

Comment: Cracked it! See my comments on the answer below if you're interested :) doesn't make any sense to me, but it's working now! Phew! Thanks for having a look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did notice the problem in Chrome as well. By just adding a background to the :before you can actually see what is happening (a trick i often use), or you could try the 3D view in Firefox. Your suspicion was right, the brace is actualy lying on top of the link. This makes sence as the DOM is rendered before the css is apllied. Adding a z-index did solve the problem though. I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KzQZQ/1

This should solve it. Strange that this did not work for you, but perhaps you where doing something wrong... Let us know if you have any more issues with this.

Comment: Thanks Peter! Looks great! But… I've tried translating the jsfiddle to my website and the :before content disappears entirely! I've used the exact css (and updated the html to reflect my in-construction site) on the jsfiddle and it works, but I can't work out why it's not working (or more, what it's conflicting with) on my site… Here's the page: http://tempertemper.net/index2 I can't spot the pseudo element in the 3D view in Firefox…

Comment: Oh, sorry, here's the working jsfiddle with the exact code from my site: http://jsfiddle.net/tempertemper/KzQZQ/2/

Comment: I've been having a play and it looks like the background image on the .wrap element I'm using was covering the :before. Strange as it's about 5 elements back in the hierarchy! I've added the bg image to the body element instead and all is well! CSS baffles me sometimes :D Thanks very much for your help @petervr